# Jsoup result display in a browser

Tags: java, jsoup

I have set text of an input field of a html page using jsoup. Now I want to display that webpage in a browser with changed value. How can I do it ?

Comment: Are you asking how to open html file in browser?

Comment: yup.... but the html file should have the changes i have made using Jsoup

Comment: Save String from JSoup to file

Comment: I didn't get your point ...

Comment: document.html() output changed document, save result to File or console, do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `document` is JSoup Document with changes, save the `document.html()` to file.

```
 FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            String content = document.html()
            File newTextFile = new File("C:/test/test.txt");
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            fileWriter.write(content);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WriteStringToFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WriteStringToFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

and open this file in browser.

Comment: ok got it ... for instance i want to set my user id on gmail login page ... what will be the steps... ?

Comment: Accept this and ask another question. You will earn points after accepting.

Comment: Dont comment with thanks, use upvote :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow :) Cheers.